# GNU Make does not execute first target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am working on a complex make file that was written by other developers, this makefile also includes other makefiles.

I put a dumb rule at the beginning of the makefile, then invoked the makefile without specifying a target expecting that the first rule executes only (which echoes something), but I found that other rules got invoked.

I wonder is there any cases where other rules may get evaluated before the first rule (maybe because of includes or secondary expansions or others)?

Answer (score 1):

The very first (non-pattern non-leading-dot) rule that make sees is the default target (by default). Whether that comes from the `Makefile` or some included makefile doesn't matter.

Additionally, a makefile can override that by setting the [`.DEFAULT_GOAL` special variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_002eDEFAULT_005fGOAL-_0028define-default-goal_0029).

This is discussed in the [How `make` Processes a Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#How-Make-Works) section of the GNU make manual.

> By default, `make` starts with the first target (not targets whose names start with ‘.’). This is called the *default goal*. (*Goals* are the targets that make strives ultimately to update. You can override this behavior using the command line (see [Arguments to Specify the Goals](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Goals)) or with the `.DEFAULT_GOAL` special variable (see [Other Special Variables)](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Special-Variables).